# Redshift: Find MAX in list disregarding non-incremental numbers

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, gaps-and-islands

I work for a sports film analysis company. We have teams with unique team IDs and I would like to find the number of consecutive weeks they have uploaded film to our site moving backwards from today. Each upload also has its own row in a separate table that I can join on teamid and has a unique date of when it was uploaded. So far I put together a simple query that pulls each unique DATEDIFF(week) value and groups on teamid.

```
Select teamid, MAX(weekdiff)
(Select teamid, DATEDIFF(week, dateuploaded, GETDATE()) as weekdiff 
from leroy_events
group by teamid, weekdiff)
```

What I am given is a list of teamIDs and unique weekly date differences. I would like to then find the max for each teamID without breaking an increment of 1. For example, if my data set is:

```
Team     datediff
11453    0
11453    1
11453    2
11453    5
11453    7
11453    13
```

I would like the max value for team: 11453 to be 2.

Any ideas would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified your example assuming that I already have a table with `weekdiff` column. That would be what you're doing with `DATEDIFF` to calculate it.

First, I'm using `LAG()` window function to assign previous value (in ordered set) of a weekdiff to the current row.

Then, using a `WHERE` condition I'm retrieving `max(weekdiff)` value that has a previous value which is `current_value - 1` for consecutive `weekdiff`s.

**Data:**

```
create table leroy_events ( teamid int, weekdiff int);
insert into leroy_events values (11453,0),(11453,1),(11453,2),(11453,5),(11453,7),(11453,13);
```

**Code:**

```
WITH initial_data AS (
Select 
    teamid, 
    weekdiff,
    lag(weekdiff,1) over (partition by teamid order by weekdiff) as lag_weekdiff
from
    leroy_events
)
SELECT
  teamid,
  max(weekdiff) AS max_weekdiff_consecutive
FROM
  initial_data
WHERE weekdiff = lag_weekdiff + 1 -- this insures retrieving max() without breaking your consecutive increment
GROUP BY 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7b8c2/2) with your sample data to see how this code works.

Result:

```
teamid  max_weekdiff_consecutive
11453   2
```

Comment: thanks a ton for your help. Does this also take in to effect number series that start later in the spectrum? For example a team with a weekdiff data set of 45, 46, 47... would this query return 47, or would it not return at all? If it is returning 47, is there a way to not return at all?

Comment: My question in the comment above may have already been answered by John in his answer below. He was able to make a CASE comparison to see if the MIN was equal to 0. Combining with your answer here, it looks like I have an awesome final product!

Comment: Yes it is possible, but I see John has already helped you with that. Please remember to upvote answers that have helped you with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL window functions to probe relationships between rows of the table.  In this case the `lag()` function can be used to look at the previous row relative to a given order and grouping.  That way you can determine whether a given row is part of a group of consecutive rows.

You still need overall to aggregate or filter to reduce the number of rows for each group of interest (i.e. each team) to 1.  It's convenient in this case to aggregate.  Overall, it might look like this:

```
select
  team,
  case min(datediff)
    when 0 then max(datediff)
    else -1
  end as max_weeks
from (
    select
      team,
      datediff,
      case
        when (lag(datediff) over (partition by team order by datediff) != datediff - 1)
          then 0
        else 1
      end as is_consec
    from diffs
  ) cd
where is_consec = 1
group by team
```

The inline view just adds an `is_consec` column to the data, marking whether each row is part of a group of consecutive rows.  The outer query filters on that column (you cannot filter directly on a window function), and chooses the maximum `datediff` from the remaining rows for each team.

There are a few subtleties there:

- The `case` expression in the inline view is written as it is to exploit the fact that the `lag()` computed for the first row of each partition will be `NULL`, which does not evaluate unequal (nor equal) to any value.  Thus the first row in each partition is always marked consecutive.
- The `case` testing `min(datediff)` in the outer `select` clause picks up teams that have no record with `datediff = 0`, and assigns `-1` to column `max_weeks` for them.
- It would also have been possible to mark rows non-consecutive if the first in their group did not have `datediff = 0`, but then you would lose such teams from the results altogether.